# Laravel variable in og:tag

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5, share

After looking around for a while I haven't found what I was looking for, so here I go.

**Is there a way to set facebook's og:tags with a variable from your database?**

I am using Laravel 5.2, and I have a app.blade with my html template where I call a `@section('content')` to show each specific page.

In the app.blade (master page) I have this code

```
<meta property="og:url"           content="@yield('url')" />
<meta property="og:type"          content="@yield('type')" />
<meta property="og:title"         content="@yield('ogtitle')" />
<meta property="og:description"   content="@yield('description')" />
<meta property="og:image"         content="@yield('image')" />
```

Which I set on every specific page like this:

```
@section('url', Request::fullUrl())
@section('image', 'http://www.myurl.eu/img/share.jpg')
@section('type', 'article')
@section('ogtitle', 'Title | Careers')
@section('description', 'My personal website title')
```

Now I have a section in my website **myurl.eu/careers** where I have several detail pages for each open job position. Now I would like to set the `og:title` and the `og:description` to a variable from my database.

Trying this (below) did not fetch anything (so sharing is blank) after debuggin and scraping the [facebook tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) a few times.

```
@section('description', $job->description)
```

or

```
@section('description', {{$job->description}})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you have to share related data to your views if you want to have meta tags in all views, then do something like this:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<title>The Tittle </title>

<meta property="og:title" content="{{ $data->title}}" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ $data->description}}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ $data->page_url}}" />
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ $data->imag_url}}"   />
...
</head>
```

Comment: If I use this approach I have to set the data in my masterpage and define it once.. I want it to be different for each page (which works) but now I need it to be filled with data from database (doesn't work).

Comment: Share your data to views which is come from database.

Comment: How would you share different data for each view to 1 masterpage? How would you define $data and where?

Comment: Oh ok, now it works. I think I understand what you said now.. Althoug you have to rescrape every detail page on facebook debug graph. How do you fix this for a site managed by the client with a custom CMS (to add new detailpages).

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this. (Specific data to all views)

```
 public function boot()
   {
//        $notifyDate = $date->addDays(-3);
    view()->composer('partials.header', function($view)
    {
        $date = Carbon::now();
        $notifyDate = $date->addDays(3);
      $view->with('notify', DB::table('purchases')
          ->join('stock_item', 'stock_item.stm_id','=','purchases.item_id')
          ->join('brands', 'brands.bid','=','purchases.brand_id')
          ->join('categories', 'categories.cat_id','=','purchases.category_id')
          ->select('purchases.*','stock_item.item_name','brands.brand_name','categories.category_name')
          ->where('purchases.expire_date', '<=', $notifyDate)
          ->where('check_exp', 0)->get());
    });

}
```